# Посоветуйте сервис генерации документации для Python

Tags: python, документация

Мне понадобилось написать документацию для API, написанного на базе Python (cherrypy).
Хотелось бы максимально автоматизировать процесс, например добавить комментарий с тэгом к функции, чтобы сервис сам собрал все функции и их параметры из файла в справочный html файл.
Есть ли такой сервис?
Очень не хочется заниматься тупым копированием.

Comment: гляньте [тут](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-epytext.html)

Answer (score 2):

Широкоиспользуемой библиотекой для генерации документации является Sphinx—как CPython так и многие Питон библиотеки её используют.

[Sphinx autodoc расширение](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html) может генерировать документацию из docstrings. Могут быть использованы различные форматы, к примеру [`numpydoc`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpydoc) позволяет autodoc распознавать специфичный для numpy формат документации, используемой в docstrings.

Для быстрого просмотра документации, сохранённой в docstring, можно использовать pydoc модуль/команду из стандартной библиотеки. Встроенная `help()` использует pydoc для генерации текстовой документации для просмотра в консоли.

Примеры других инструментов по генерации документации для проектов написанных на Питоне, [можно в вики посмотреть](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DocumentationTools).

Answer (score 1):

Один из самых распространенных инструментов для автогенерирования API документации называется [**swagger**](http://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/).
При желании вместе с функциональностью "сделай мне документ по описанию API" можно использовать целую экосистему open-source инструментов, так или иначе облегчающих работу с вашим API.

Не знаю насколько он популярен среди питонистов, но с питоном работать тоже умеет.

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал `apidoc` достаточно просто, быстро. Вот [страничка](http://apidocjs.com/)